# Binding Combobox SelectedItem by a field's value

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, binding, combobox

Combobox bind to a set of `Provinces`, `Village` object has `ProvinceID` field and i want to bind SelectedItem of Combobox to a Province with Village's ProvinceID.

My code is:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ProvincesList}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="ProvinceName" 
          SelectedValuePath="ProvinceID" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Village.ProvinceID}" />
```

But SelectedItem is anything.

Comment: So each Province has a property Village, which has a field ProvinceID?  If that's the case, the issue is that you cannot bind to fields; only properties are supported.

Comment: @Dan Bryant: Province has a list of Villages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your binding direction is `OneWay` and BindingEngine of SL can't propagate UI changes to your object's property, hence you must add `Mode=TwoWay` at end of binding expression.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question, but what about setting the ComboBox's ValueMember to ProvinceID?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice is that that is not the correct syntax for binding to a control.

```
   SelectedValue="{Binding Village.ProvinceID}"
```

Should be

```
   SelectedValue="<%# Village.ProvinceID %>"
```

Comment: I think you're in the wrong language... :-) The OP is in XAML.

Comment: Possibly.  It doesn't say in the original question, so I thought it was asp.net.